# Laravel update all users age by x

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I want to update all users in my database with an age value which I get from my request.
How do I manage this?
I somehow need the current value in the db and multiple it.

```
    DB::table('customers')
        ->update([
            'age' => DB::raw('column1 * 2'),
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that the name of the `field` in your `$request` is `multiple`, you can `iterate` over your `customer` records and update each of them, applying your `multiple` value to their `age`:

```php
// grab the `multiple` value from your request
$multiple = $request->get('multiple');

// get all your customers, loop over them and update each record
Customer::all()->each(function ($customer) use ($multiple) {
    $customer->update(['age' => $customer->age * $multiple]);
});
```

If you want to use the `QueryBuilder` rather than `Eloquent`, then you can do the following:

```php
DB::table('customers')->get()->each(function ($customer) use ($multiple) {
    DB::table('customers')
        ->where('id', $customer->id)
        ->update(['age' => $customer->age * $multiple]);
});
```

Comment: Ah right sorry, the request value which I received is going to be used for all users

Comment: Right, and the same value (`multiple`) is used to update all users in my example.

Comment: I get this:
    "message": "Call to undefined method stdClass::update()",

Comment: @iasnion123 Apologies, I completely forgot `DB::table()->get()` doesn't return eloquent model instances. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Peppermintology sorry, I forgot to write the reason for downvote, what you have suggested works fine, but the problem is that you have taken multiple records from database and in a for loop updated them . the problem is for a table with 1000 rows that needs to be updated, you have queried the database for 1001 times.
I have provided an alternative and Ill update it with some thing that I would do, its not much but its honest work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to update a column based on a value as an input that is provided by the user.

Also notice I have used double quotation.

```
DB::table('your_table')
->where('some_column', $someValue)
->update(array(
    'column1' => DB::raw("column1 * $your_input_variable")
));
```

Comment: This method introduces an SQL injection vulnerability as the input variable here isn't sanitised before passing to the query builder.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the N+1 problem, I will advise you use the Eloquent's "WhereIn" method. The idea is that you build the list of items to update within the logic instead of hitting the db server N no of times in a loop as others suggested.

```
$itemTypes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; //loop through your request payload and make this list.
$columns = [[
    'name' => 'Ezugudor',
    'age' => '18', 
    'rank' => 13 
],[
    'name' => 'Mathew',
    'age' => '13', 
    'rank' => 1 
]]; //loop through your request payload and make this list.

ItemTable::whereIn('item_id', $itemTypes)
->update($columns);
```

Answer (score -2):

A cleaner way to do that

```
$items = Model::all();
$insertData = collect();

foreach ($items as $item)
{
    $insertData->push([
        'id' => $item['id'],
        'otherstuff' => $item['name']),
        'age' => $item['age'] * 2,
        'more other stuff' => $item['itmPrice'],
    ]);
}

// chunks of 1000 insert into db
foreach ($insertData->chunk(1000) as $chunk)
{
    DB::table('table_name')
    ->upsert(
        $chunk->toArray(), // array of data that is going to be inserted or updated
        ['id'], // array of the column names that should be used for finding the updatable row
        [ 'age'] // values that will be updated
    );
}
```

- `upsert` docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#upserts)

Comment: I would like to point out your contradiction. You say use `SQL` as it is `'faster, easier and more reliable'` then add a `'cleaner'` solution which uses `QueryBuilder`. I would argue your update is not cleaner at all. I would also like to point out your update has the same performance issue my solution has, which you downvoted it because of the performance issue.

Comment: This method introduces an SQL injection vulnerability as the `$your_value` here isn't sanitized before adding it to the statement.

Comment: @Peppermintology if you think they have the same performance I have nothing to say.
consider thinking a little about why I chose to use a foreach with chunk instead of upserting the whole $insertData
good luck