# Saving a collection in the database without iterating over each element and without inserting new records

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I simply want to save a collection to the database after processing it in my application.

```
$data = SomeModel::all();
$data = DataProcessor::process($data);

//Now I want to save the result back to the database...

//This doesn't work since it's a collection so you get the error: 
//"Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist."

$data ->save();

//This works but is not feasible due to the amount (thousands) of records needed to be updated

foreach($data as $dat){
    $dat->save();
}

//This doesn't work because I'm updating, not inserting new records. 
//So I get integrity constraint violation on id

SomeModel::insert($data);
```

I feel this should be a common practice with a pretty straightforward solution but I've been looking around and haven't found anything.

Comment: Eloquent isn't the best tool for the job as you have noted, there are a couple of things you can do, use the ORM which is generally better for large DB operations and chunk your updates. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68054936/laravel-update-all-users-age-by-x

Comment: Try upserts: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts

Comment: @jssDev Thanks, works just fine. If you make that an answer I could accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According docs, you could try upserts: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts